# Automating email through python with smtplib, using sending from gmail sending to iusd (school district), does not go through

Tags: python, email, automation, smtp

I'm trying to automate emails but I'm sending it from gmail.com to iusd.org (school district). So far its worked when I've sent from gmail to another gmail account, but when I try to send to an iusd.org account it doesn't send. What would I need to change in order for this to send? Also is there a cap to the number of emails that I can send to? I have about 110 people that I'm trying to email through this.

```
> import smtplib
> 
> server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp@gmail.com",465)
> server.login("myemail@gmail.com","mypassword")
> 
> messages =
> {"otheremail@iusd.org":"www.googlesheets.com","otheremail2@iusd.org":"www.googlesheets.com"}
> for email, link in messages.items():   
>     link = "Hello there, \n \n Attached is a link to your your spreadsheet: \n" + link + "\n \n
>     Sincerely, \n John"   
>     server.sendmail("myemail@gmail.com",email,link)
> server.quit()
```

Comment: You should inspect the return value of `server.sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

First think I would try is changing the debug-level to 1 (or better 2).
From the official docs:

SMTP.set_debuglevel(level):

Set the debug output level. A value of 1 or True for level results in debug messages for connection and for all messages sent to and received from the server. A value of 2 for level results in these messages being timestamped.

Comment: Okay I set the debug level to 1 and I'm getting a 250 code for both accounts account, which is supposed to mean that the requested mail action is complete. I'm receiving the mail for my gmail account but not for my iusd account. is it possible that the school district might be blocking mail from certain sources?

Comment: 250 is good. Yes, it would be possible either by firewall or blacklisting to limit the access, but you would get either a timeout or an error message. From here on the best chance is to look into the chunks of your return and dissect them. My bet is, you are receiving a multipart message  and handling them incorrectly.